# Angular 2 TypeScript functions with return value and binding it to HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am a beginner with Angular and TypeScript and I have a function like

```
jajal(varname:string) {
  switch (varname) {
    case "foo":
      varname = "foo-return"
      break;
    case "bar":
      varname = "bar-return"
      break;
    case "ok":
      varname = "ok-return"
      break;    

    default:
      varname="not processed"
      break;
}
```

and the HTML template like

```
<ion-item button class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" *ngFor="let user of users">
  <p>jajal({{user.icon}})</p>
  <h2>{{user.icon}}</h2>
  <ion-icon name="arrow-forward" item-right></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

(this is an Ionic project).

I just wanna sent the user.icon value from HTML (p element) template to the `jajal()` function and get return value but it doesn't work.

Comment: not sure if you can call a function like that.. maybe try {{jajal(user.icon)}}

Comment: your template will just print jajal( then show the icon..

Comment: you can't. Either try `{{jajal(user.icon)}}` like @SurajRao pointed out, or use `<p [innerHtml]="jajal(user.icon)"></p>`

Comment: hey its work with {{jajal(user.icon)}} thax guys ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Looks like what you need is a pipe. you can define a customer pipe like this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'jajal'})
export class JajalPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(varname: string): string {
    switch (varname) {
      case "foo":
        varname = "foo-return"
        break;
      case "bar":
        varname = "bar-return"
        break;
      case "ok":
        varname = "ok-return"
        break;    

      default:
        varname="not processed"
        break;
    }

    return varname;
  }
}
```

And use it in your template like this

```
{{user.icon | jajal}}
```

Wish this would help. And you'd better check the doc first, you will find it useful, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html